# Opening BasicMenu.xcodeproj fails on the new ECSlidingViewController 2

Tags: ios7, xcode5, ecslidingviewcontroller

Is it possible to open the BasicMenu.xcodeproj on xcode on the new version of  ECSlidingViewController without having to do it via Examples.xcworkspace? I am trying to just work through the BasicMenu example specifically and when I do I get this error:
 **ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Comment: I copied the ECSlidingViewController into the BasicMenu target in Xcode and this seemed to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the dependencies to ECSlingViewController won't be available.

You should be able to work with the BasicMenu project inside the workspace. CocoaPods is not required, the repo includes the installed dependencies.

Comment: Thank you @Michael so it wouldn't be advisable to setup outside of the workspace?

Comment: If you're planning to contribute back then use the workspace. Otherwise you're free to do whatever.