# library not found for -lPods when i am using ECSliding Controller

Tags: ecslidingviewcontroller

I am facing the this kind of issue in `ECSlidingContrtoller`

`ld: library not found for -lPods`

`clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: See this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324136/opening-basicmenu-xcodeproj-fails-on-the-new-ecslidingviewcontroller-2